# E2E Test Automation workflow with GitLab CI/CD

Tags: testing, automated-tests, gitlab-ci, e2e-testing, system-testing

I am to build a test automation system for E2E testing for a company. The product is React/Node.JS based runs in a cloud (Docker & Kubernetes). The code is stored in GitLab repositories for which there are CI/CD pipelines setup for test/lint/deployment.

I plan to use Jest for test orchestration and Selenium / Appium for the UI testing (FRW being in TypeScript), while creating a generator to test our proprietary backend interface.
My code is in a similar repository and will be containerized and uploaded to the test environment.

In my former workplaces we used TeamCity and similar tools to manage test sessions but I do not seem to be able to find the perfect link between our already set up GitLab CI/CD and the E2E testing framework.

I know it could be implemented as part of the pipeline, but for me it seems lacking (which can also be because of my inexperience)

Could you advise some tools/methods for handling test session management for system testing in such an environment?
(with a GUI where I can see the progress of all sessions, being able to manage them, run / rerun / run on certain platforms only, etc)

Comment: Hey did you find the answer. I am in same situation